# flume to copy RDBMS data in near real time

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, flume

Can we configure flume to copy data in a near time manner from a table of any RDBMS e.g. Oracle / Teradata to HDFS.

I know sqoop is the standard method to use to copy data back-n-forth from RDBMS to HDFS, but that normally works in batch mode and I want the copy to happen in near real time mode.

If yes, then can I get a small working example of it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Sources for RDBMS databases. But you can take advantage of `exec` type in Apache Flume. See an example [here](https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/11093.streaming-oracle-database-logs-to-hdfs-with-flume).

Comment: Thanks, the example explains streaming of Oracle log file; but here I am interested in streaming of Oracle table's data. Will it be possible by using corresponding tablespace etc.

Comment: Yes It is possible. You can mix it with this example as it uses MySQL Table Data to Flume : https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/11114.streaming-mysql-database-table-data-to-hdfs-with-flume

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you please also let me know what ever the data pulled can this be loaded in any hive table straight a way? Actually I haven't the environment available with me, so can't verify it.

Comment: Yes of course. There is HiveSink that you can load your Oracle table data into it. Here is an example for HiveSink in Flume: http://henning.kropponline.de/2015/05/19/hivesink-for-flume/